# How to stop Spring redirect url getting encoded

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

i am using below code in spring 
return new ModelAndView("https://test.com?query1=value1&query2=Value2")
That is getting encoded to value = https://test.com?query1%3Dvalue1%26query2%3Value2 in the browser.

How to correct this,  What changes needed to make it correct formed url.
is this tomcat or browser doing this?

Problem is i am trying to get by parameter by name but not able to get it. As the name has been changed with some special character.

request.getParameter("query1")

Comment: What is the problem with encoded Url?It's done by browser.

Comment: Problem is i am trying to get by parameter by name but not able to get it. As the name has been changed with some special character.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add those attributes to the model and view, just as

```
ModelAndView res = new ModelAndView("https://test.com");
res.addAttribute("query1", value1);
res.addAttribute("query2", value2);
```

To retrieve them, you can use

```
 Object param1 = (Object) request.getAttribute("query1");
```

being Object your type of Object for the attribute

Update 1:

If last try didn't work, go ahead and use this alternative:

```
String message = "SomeText"
return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "welcome", "message", message);
```

This message variable will be available in URL as a GET request

```
http://localhost:80/test/welcome?message=SomeText
```

Update 2:

I suppose you are using Controllers, so try to add to the RequestMapping annotation the following attribute

```
@RequestMapping(value = "...whatever you have", produces = 
   "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: This will also added to the query paramters and will be in encoded form

Comment: This approach also browser is encoding the value.

Comment: thank you it works for me. but instead using addAttribute, I success when using addObject